# AWS Code Build Python Library Error GLIBC_2.29 not found

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS Code Build project and I am getting this error from the ***build*** step.

> Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIi1UsL2/libpython3.7m.so.1.0':
> dlopen: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by
> /tmp/_MEIi1UsL2/libpython3.7m.so.1.0)

These are the container's environment:

```
Environment:
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0
```

and as for the build spec:

```
version: 0.2
          phases:
            install:
              commands:
                - curl -L https://oni.ca/runway/latest/linux -o runway
            pre_build:
              commands:
                - ls -a
                - chmod +x runway
                - export SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY=$SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY
                - yum install epel-release -y
                - yum install python-pip -y
            build:
              commands:
                - ./runway plan --ci --deploy-environment $DEPLOY_ENV
            post_build:
              commands: 
                - ./runway deploy --ci --deploy-environment $DEPLOY_ENV 
              finally:
                - echo "Completed!"
```

Knowing that this same code was working a week ago!

Comment: How about you contact support or file a bug ticket? This isn't really a useful question, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

I was using latest for the runway version and 8 days ago there was a new release and it broke the deployment because the image uses an older version of GLIBC(2.26 instead of 2.29) so I went back to the older version and things are working fine.

```
- curl -L https://oni.ca/runway/1.16.0/linux -o runway
```

instead of

```
- curl -L https://oni.ca/runway/latest/linux -o runway
```